# Can't convert app to module in Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, web-applications, module

I went to the *Google App Engine Admin Console* to convert my *app* to a *module*. It instructed me to copy and paste a snippet of code into my project's `app.yaml` file, which I did. But when I attempt to deploy my module, this error is printed in the logs:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output --- Your application currently has custom performance
settings that are not compatible with the Modules feature. You must either clear or
migrate these application-level settings before you can upload a non-default module. See
the Performance section of the Application Settings page of the Admin Console for more
information. --- end server output ---
```

I don't have any *"custom performance settings"* in my application. Why can't I convert my GAE app to a module?

Comment: So what does "the Performance section of the Application Settings page of the Admin Console" for your app tell you have set in that regard?

Comment: It just says to migrate the app, and it has a button. I click on it, and it says I have to copy-paste a code snippet, which I did already.

Comment: @NarawaGames what's the snippet?

Comment: @NarawaGames mind including your app.yaml (or xml, depending if you're in Java or Python) and the module.yaml (or xml again)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beneath where it shows the code snippet, if you scroll down the page, there is a confirmation button. If you click the confirmation button, then deploy again using your new app.yaml file, you should be able to deploy without getting the error message.

For other users experiencing this problem, here is how to do it in full:

Go to the legacy Google App Engine Admin Console:

https://appengine.google.com/

Then go to your application > Application Settings.

There should be a section on the settings page titled 'Performance Settings Migration for Modules'. Click the 'Migrate' button. When it shows you the code snippet, scroll down the page and click the confirmation button.